# How to run an AutoLisp routine (ATTOUT) from AutoCad Core Console 2016

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I would like to run the ATTOUT routine on all the blocks of a .dwg file, using the Core Console for automating an application..

I'm using the default "attout.lsp" in the Express folder of my AutoCAD 2016 installation, since i want to use it on ALL BLOCKS and dont need to select a specific block.

i tried :

```
accoreconsole.exe /i C:/<pathing_to_my_dwg_file>/sample1.dwg /s test-attout.scr
```

where test-attout.scr is :

```
(load "attout.lsp" "/omg it"s not working)
```

the results are below:

```
`Redirect stdout (file: C:\Users\lboey\AppData\Local\Temp\accc64962).
AutoCAD Core Engine Console - Copyright Autodesk, Inc 2009-2013.
Regenerating layout.

Regenerating model.
..
**** System Variable Changed ****
1 of the monitored system variables has changed from the preferred value. Use SY
1 of the monitored system variables has changed from the preferred value. Use SY
SVARMONITOR command to view changes.


Command:
Command:

Command:
Command: (load "attout" "omg it's not loading")_quit


Command:`
```

I'm a noobie in AutoCAD and any advice is very much appreciated..

Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question:

1. Create a my_script.scr file

> ```
> (load "C:\\Program Files\\...\\my_routine.lsp")> 
> att-out
> ```

2. Create an AutoLisp routine file my_routine.lsp

> (defun c:att-out ()  (load "attout")  (setq out (strcat (getvar>
>   "dwgprefix")  (acet-filename-path-remove (acet-filename-ext-remove>
>   (getvar "dwgname"))) .txt" ))  (setq ss (ssget "X" '((0 . "INSERT")
>   (66 . 1))))  (bns_attout out ss)  )

3. Call the script with acad.exe

> acad.exe C:\Program Files...\a_simple_dwg.dwg /b my_script.scr

Autocad Core Console is in it's early development stage now and therefore the easiest way to automate a chain of operations is by using AutoLisp.

Answer (score 2):

This command (ATTOUT) will show a dialog, that's why it's not working on Console. Also, any LISP that uses COM will not work either (vl-load-com)

Comment: the ATTOUT command will not work, it was not designed for AutoCAD Console... you may need to mimic this feature, without the UI requirements (acet-ui-)

Answer (score -1):

***my_routine.lsp*** works on Autocad 2011 with small a adjustment

```
(defun c:att-out () (load "attout") (setq out (strcat (getvar "dwgprefix") (acet-filename-path-remove (acet-filename-ext-remove (getvar "dwgname"))) ".txt" )) (setq ss (ssget "X" '((0 . "INSERT") (66 . 1)))) (bns_attout out ss))
```

Thanx @user3336544